# How to parse data type function Array() { [native code] }

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express

I have a Postgres/Express api with Users who commit Acts.

I have the following route

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => { 
  // loop through users
  console.log('crons: getting users');
  const users = await User.query();
  for (const user of users) {
    const lastAct = await Act
      .query()
      .where('users_id', user.id)
      .orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
      .limit(1);
    console.log('Users last act is :', JSON.parse(lastAct))
  };

  res.json({
    success: true, message: 'ok' 
  }); 
});
```

lastAct returns an object like:

```
[ Act {
    id: 1,
    deed: 'Writing',
    users_id: 8,
    created_at: 2019-12-15T13:19:04.243Z,
    updated_at: 2019-12-15T13:19:04.243Z } ]
```

constructor method returns data type for this object: function Array() { [native code] }

I can't figure out how to parse this to access the attributes id, users_id etc

Comment: Uh, you don't have to parse anything, it already is an array containing one object, and you can just access it? Like `console.log(lastAct[0].deed)`

Comment: I tried that. I get eg `(node:57612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'deed' of undefined`

Comment: Then probably not all of your `users` have a `lastAct`, and you should check for the `lastAct.length` (number of returned rows) first before trying to access it.

Comment: in my model, Users have Acts. lastAct is a const that houses the object return of a query to find the last act for a specific user. For the uses with no Acts, the lastAct returns an empty array. If a user has Acts, the query returns the object in the form shown above, which is what I am trying to parse.  the array is formatted as [Act {...}]. I think `Act` is what is throwing me off fwiw

Comment: It just means that the object in the array is an `Act` instance, that's how `console.log` displays it.

Comment: that solves it. Wrapped the console.log with `if (lastAct.length > 0)` to eliminate the empty arrays. Thanks!